# Cloudberry explorer for s3 with AWS session token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudberry

I am trying to connect to AWS s3 using cloudberry s3 explorer. But I don't see an option to add the `AWS session token`, without the session token why I try adding an account with `AWS Access key` and `AWS Secret Key`, I get below error,

[image]

But I am able to connect to AWS s3 using AWS cli. There I can specify my `AWS session token` in the configuration. I don't the option in cloudberry explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct -- CloudBerry Explorer does not access temporary credentials.

It also does not recognize credentials stored in `.aws\credentials`.

You should either use permanent credentials (that do not include a Session Token), or contact CloudBerry Labs for assistance. Perhaps also lodge a feature request with them.